# Can I declare a CSS of a parent?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

I have this code :

```
<div class="main_parent">
    <a href="www.google.it">
        <img src="/path/image.jpg" alt="image" />
    </a>
</div>
```

and I'd like to set the attribute `text-decoration:none;` to the link that contains an image.

So, somethings like :

```
.main_parent img < a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

but of course it doesnt works. How can I do it with CSS 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible.
Some smart people also wrote about this: http://css-tricks.com/7701-parent-selectors-in-css/

You read CSS selectors from left to right. So there is no real syntax for this right now.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, you can't.  CSS can only traverse the DOM downwards.  If javascript/jQuery is an option for you, you could use that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible via CSS. You would have to use JavaScript and assign the style via DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it with CSS3. There is no parent selector unfortunately.